# Арифметические операции с числами четверной точности (binary 128)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, точность

Требуется реализовать возможность работы с числами повышенной точности без использования готовых библиотек, например, quadmath (__float128). Может быть, существуют какие-то дельные описания алгоритмов как производить сложение и умножение [таких экзотических чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)? Несколько дней гугления пока не привели к положительным результатам :( Был бы признателен за любые идеи или наброски решений в виде кода.

Comment: А зачем свою писать то?

Comment: Это учебная задача. Таков путь

Comment: Эта задача труднее чем ВКР в университете. И то к ВКР ещё есть научный руководитель, которому и стоит задать этот вопрос. Вообще найти что-либо о 128 битной плавающей запятой врядли получится сверх того, что есть в википедии. А всё потому, что даже дабл для большинства задач избыточен. А уж 128 бит...

Comment: Этот вариант был предложен в качестве одной из четырех лабораторных работ по вычмату, 2 курс. Сами в шоке.

Comment: если ты уже можешь решить подобную задачу, то уже можешь пробовать устроится на работу. Если же нет, то серавно не сможешь сдать лабу. Видимо преподаватель намекает что университет бесполезен. Лично я считаю, что в универе потратил впустую много времени. Лично мне иногда даже кошмары снятся про дурацкие сложные задания, которые ещё и надо делать за бесплатно.